# Android multiline TextView horizontally and vertically scrollable no line wrap

Tags: android, textview, line-breaks, horizontal-scrolling, vertical-scrolling

Is there a way to configure Android multiline TextView to be both horizontally and vertically scrollable and to respect new line characters in the shown string (= break lines only in the new line char)? I simply want the same behavior that is common in most source code viewers/editors and anyway it is what I want - I want to show a simple xml source code in that TextView.

It would be nice to configure it in the layout xml but I have no problem with runtime settings in java code.

Comment: Have you tried setting `android:scrollbars = "vertical|horizontal"`? or wrapping it in a `scrollView`?

Comment: Yes, I have tried it but it has no effect to line breaking. Maybe I am doing something wrong and full layout.xml would help me but now I expect that it is not possible to configure TextView as I want.

Comment: Can you add your layout file code to the question? Also try `android:maxLines="<some arbitrary integer>"`